# CSS animated slide down when lower element gets removed (elements in container with relative position)

Tags: html, css

I've got a script which create a simple container for error message boxes and if needed create these boxes in it. The container got a fixed width, like the boxes but not a fixed height, so the boxes stack about each other in a vertical row. Also the boxes in the container got `position: relative`.

Picture of the container & boxes:

[image]

Now what I want is, that if you remove a box, the above boxes slides down, animated. I tried it with CSS transitions but it didn't work (I'm pretty new to transitions, so I don't even know if it's possible with `position: relative` because the `top` and `bottom` properties aren't set).

Example [See picture for reference]: I click on box 3, box 3 gets removed, box 1 and 2 slide down next to 4, 5, and 6. This works, but it isn't animated yet.

Question: Is it possible to do this with CSS, and if so, how?

HTML:

```
<div class="popBoxContainer popBoxContainerRight">
    <div class="popBox error" onclick="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" title="click to close">
        <p class="popBox__title">error</p>
        <span class="popBox__msg">Test-Box-1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="popBox error" onclick="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" title="click to close">
        <p class="popBox__title">error</p>
        <span class="popBox__msg">Test-Box-2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="popBox error" onclick="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" title="click to close">
        <p class="popBox__title">error</p>
        <span class="popBox__msg">Test-Box-3</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.popBoxContainer {
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0 10px 15px 10px;
}
.popBoxContainerRight {
    right: 0;
}
.popBoxContainerLeft {
    left: 0;
}
.popBox {
    padding: 15px 25px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.03);
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.popBox:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.popBox .popBox__title {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.popBox.error .popBox__title {
    color: #FF5252;
}
.popBox.warning .popBox__title {
    color: #FFDB70;
}
.popBox .popBox__msg {
    color: #4c4c4c;
}
```

JS:

```
function initPopBox(side) {
    if(document.getElementsByClassName('popBoxContainer').length < 1) {
        var box = document.createElement('div');
        box.className = 'popBoxContainer';
        if(side != "") {
            if(side == "left") {
                box.className += ' popBoxContainerLeft';
            } else {
                box.className += ' popBoxContainerRight';
            }
        } else {
            box.className += ' popBoxContainerRight';
        }
        document.body.appendChild(box);
    }
}

function popBox(type, txt) {
    var boxCon = document.getElementsByClassName('popBoxContainer');
    if(boxCon.length < 1) {
        initPopBox();
    }
    switch(type) {
        case 'error':
            boxCon[0].innerHTML += '<div class="popBox error" onclick="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" title="click to close"><p class="popBox__title">error</p><span class="popBox__msg">'+txt+'</span></div>';
            break;
        case 'warning':
            boxCon[0].innerHTML += '<div class="popBox warning" onclick="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" title="click to close"><p class="popBox__title">warning</p><span class="popBox__msg">'+txt+'</span></div>';
            break;
        default:
            boxCon[0].innerHTML += '<div class="popBox error" onclick="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" title="click to close"><p class="popBox__title">error</p><span class="popBox__msg">'+txt+'</span></div>';
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you need further information, like the css code, go on and comment.

Comment: @Paulie_D Well, you can certainly show/hide stuff with just CSS (e.g. a checkbox and `:selected`). I think this behavior would be possible with that and `display: none;`

Comment: Guys, I'm sorry, you don't understood me. I've got a container with boxes in it, now if i click one i remove the whole dom tree of the box per javascript, making the boxes "fall down", but its not animated, they just swap position...

Comment: @Cor3X we really need to see your existing relevant HTML to answer this. Preferably relevant CSS as well.

Comment: @TylerH I've added my Code (No html that im using, its pure JS for creating them). I call the initPopBox(side), for setting the side the container is. popBox() is for creating them in the container, if the container isnt there, it creates it with default side.

Comment: @Paulie_D Sorry, im removing the DOM tree, don't use display: none or else. My problem is they got no set position, they stacking because its relative.

Comment: @Cor3X Can you include your HTML as well, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your HTML it's hard to really solve. That being said, you can't get the desired behavior using only CSS, like Paulie_D said in the comments above. You *can* get close (if you don't need a sliding animation).

Here is a combination of CSS and jQuery that does what you want:

```js
$("label").click(function() {
    $(this).delay(600).queue(function (next) { 
        $(this).css('display', 'none'); 
        next(); 
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}

.container {
    width: 235px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: lightgrey;
    padding: 1px 0;
}

label {
    display: block;
    background: white;
    margin: 16px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    color: #c95959;
    position: relative;
}

p {
    margin-top: 12px;
    color: #3e3b3b;
}

#box1:checked ~ .container .label1, #box2:checked ~ .container .label2, #box3:checked ~ .container .label3, #box4:checked ~ .container .label4, #box5:checked ~ .container .label5, #box6:checked ~ .container .label6 {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.7s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="box1"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="box2"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="box3"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="box4"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="box5"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="box6"/>
<div class="container">
    <label class="label1" for="box1">
        <span>ERROR</span>
        <p>Test-Error-Box-1</p>
    </label>
    <label class="label2" for="box2">
        <span>ERROR</span>
        <p>Test-Error-Box-2</p>
    </label>
    <label class="label3" for="box3">
        <span>ERROR</span>
        <p>Test-Error-Box-3</p>
    </label>
    <label class="label4" for="box4">
        <span>ERROR</span>
        <p>Test-Error-Box-4</p>
    </label>
    <label class="label5" for="box5">
        <span>ERROR</span>
        <p>Test-Error-Box-5</p>
    </label>
    <label class="label6" for="box6">
        <span>ERROR</span>
        <p>Test-Error-Box-6</p>
    </label>
</div>
```

**[JSFIDDLE Example](http://jsfiddle.net/z4sgvhks/)**

Comment: Yea, you well added a jQuery command. Mine do the same with vanilla JS but jQuery animates the fadeout. This is what i needed just as a css-transition. Now i trigger a css animation when a box disapear^^ SOLVED.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use max-height here. On the original element have a max-height of whatever height you want it to be. Using height auto I don't think will work with this. There's a good example at: http://codepen.io/LFeh/pen/ICkwe

Take a look at this code:

```
.element{
  -webskit-transition: max-height 1s;
  max-height:0px;
 }
 .parentelement:hover childelement {
   max-height:50px;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, as far your answere brought the most^^ i think i could do this with max height of the container (parent of boxes), maybe it works.